# The status of the matrix $X^TAY+Y^TAX$ if the matrix $A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Say that the matrix $A$ is positive definite and the matrices $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily PD or PSD or even symmetric. Under what conditions the matrix $X^TAY+Y^TAX$ is PD, PSD, and neither?
All matrices here are square.

Comment: Can you answer the question if $A$ is the identity?

Comment: I am not sure actually!

Comment: Since any matrix can be factorized as $X^T Y$ you are asking when $M + M^T$ us PSD. Not obvious to me, though if $M$ is symmetric and PSD, the answer is obviously "YES".

Comment: you are right! All I know about $X$ and $Y$ is that $X-Y$ have spectral radius less than 1, but I doubt that would help!